# Cast a string to an integer only if it is an integer

Tags: php, types, casting

```
$value = "32 is my number";

if ($value == (integer) $value) {
    $value = (integer) $value; 
}

echo $value; // always 32
```

I understand [why this does not work](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). How would I cast a string to an integer only if it is really just an integer?

This works but it is so ugly. It seems there should be a better way:

```
$value = "32 is my number";
$new_value = $value;
$new_value = (integer) $new_value ;
$new_value = (string) $new_value;
if ($value == $new_value) {
    $value = (integer) $value;;
}
```

for clarification:
"32 is my number" should remain a string,
"32" should be converted to an integer,
"32.01" should not be changed. It's numeric but (integer) "32.01" becomes 32

Comment: Perhaps http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php ?

Comment: is_int would always be false as he has to handle a **string**, _maybe_ containing only digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why to do it, but this will do it:

```
if(ctype_digit($value)) {
    $value = (int)$value;
}
```

EDIT: It's not clear from your question whether you think `32 is my number` should be an integer or not :-(

Comment: The reason for needing to do this is I'm working with a web service that expects json encoded integers to not me quoted. I understand that it would make more sense to verify the type when initially setting the  variable but Im not able to do that in this existing code base without a lot of refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `==` comparison operator PHP does [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). This causes `$value` to be converted to an interger before it is compared to `(integer) $value` which results in them being identical.

```
 $value = "32 is my number";

if ($value === (integer) $value) { // $value is type juggled to 32 and then compared
    $value = (integer) $value; 
}

echo $value;
```

Use `===` comparison operator which compares by value *and* type to avoid this:

```
$value = "32 is my number";

if ($value === (integer) $value) { // $value is still "32 is my number"
    $value = (integer) $value; 
}

echo $value;
```

From the other answers you can see there are multiple ways to do this. You can also look into [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) as another alternative.

```
$value = "32 is my number";

if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) { 
    $value = (integer) $value; 
}

echo $value;
```

Comment: the Identical comparison would not work for me because if $value it would never evaluate true. ("1" === (integer) 1) is false because of type mismatch.  filter_var would work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

there is a function called `is_numeric()`. It tests if a string contains only numbers. I think it is exactly what you need.

```
if (is_numeric($value)) {
    $value = (integer) $value;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: is_numeric doesn't work for me because of floats. 32.01 is numeric but casting it as an int would be 32.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is_numeric` to determine whether the value passed is numeric or can be converted to numeric if its a string by returning **true** else it returns **false**.

```
$value = "32 is numeric";
if (is_numeric(trim($value))) {
$value = (double) $value; 
echo "numeric";
}
echo $value;
```

Comment: is numeric won't work for me because it will alter my floats. if value is "5.05" it is numeric but it would change if cast as int.

Comment: You can just cast it to float or double instead (`$value = (double) $value`). I guess that doesn't harm anything.